# Which variable is independent variable here?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, predictor

I am confused. Both can be used as the dependent variables. But which will be the appropriate one?

The Director of the School of Business is interested to study if there is a relationship between the hours of sleep and the age of Diploma in Business Practice students, using Regression & Correlation Analysis.

- Identify the independent (x) and dependent (y) variable.

Comment: I like to say 'predictor' variable vs. 'predicted' instead of 'indep' vs 'dependent'. You're trying go use 'hours of sleep' to predict 'age at graduation'.

Comment: In correlation analysis there is no distinction between "dependent" and "independent."  For regression, *either* answer is plausible, depending on the objective of the regression and on how the values of the variables are measured.

Comment: is it possible to use ' 'age at graduation' to predict 'hours of sleep'

Comment: Sure -- why not?  Indeed, that's the more justified application of regression, because age at graduation typically is known accurately whereas hours of sleep has to be measured somehow and is both uncertain and variable.